# what is the use of delegates in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, delegates

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When would you use delegates in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/191153/when-would-you-use-delegates-in-c)

On what condition should we use delegates

Answer (score 1):

The short answer:
When you want to pass some code to some other code

Comment: what is multicast delegates? Can anyone give some examples on that

Comment: @user455290 you should either ask another question for that or find one