# In which situation to use the Delegate concept in C#?

Tags: asp.net, delegates

I am trying to study the delegate concept in c#.

I did a sample of delegate as I studied. But I did not understood the correct situation where we using its concept effectively. 
Can any one please suggest a easy understandable situation where we use delegate.

I know the working of delegates. But still not cleared where it effectively use.

I posted my code below. Please let me know if any mistakes I did in the sample.

Thankx in advance.

**ChangePassword.ascx**

```
  <%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="ChangePassword.ascx.cs" Inherits="User_Controls_ChangePassword" %>

<div style="width:500px;clear:both;">
<div style="width:100%; clear:both;">
    <div style="width:150px; float:left;">
        <asp:Label ID="newPassword" runat="server" Text="New Password"></asp:Label>
    </div>
    <div style="width:100px; float:left;">
        <asp:TextBox ID="newPassText" runat="server" Width="200"></asp:TextBox>
    </div>
</div>
<div style="width:100%; clear:both;padding-top:20px;">
    <div style="width:150px; float:left;">
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Confirm New Password"></asp:Label>
    </div>
    <div style="width:100px; float:left;">
        <asp:TextBox ID="confirmNewPass" runat="server" Width="200"></asp:TextBox>
    </div>
</div>
<div style="width:100%; clear:both;padding-top:20px;">
    <div style="width:150px; float:left;">
        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="&nbsp;"></asp:Label>
    </div>
    <div style="width:207px; float:left;">
        <div style="float:left;">
            <asp:Button ID="changePass" runat="server" Text="Change"  /> 
        </div>
        <div style="float:right;">
            <asp:Button ID="cancelButton" runat="server" Text="Cancel" /> 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div style="width:100%; clear:both;padding-top:20px;">
    <div style="width:350px; float:left;">
        <asp:Label ID="successMessage" runat="server" Text="Passwords Changed.." ForeColor="Red" Font-Bold="true" Visible="false"></asp:Label>
    </div>
</div>
```

**ChangePassword.ascx.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class User_Controls_ChangePassword : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    public delegate void ChangePasswordDelegate(object sender, ChangePasswordEventArgs e);
    public event ChangePasswordDelegate ChangePasswordEvent;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        changePass.Click += new EventHandler(changePass_Click);
    }

    void changePass_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ChangePasswordEvent(sender, new ChangePasswordEventArgs(newPassText.Text, this) );
    }
}


public class ChangePasswordEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    private string _newPassword = "";
    private object _parent = null;

public string NewPassword
{
    get
    {
        return _newPassword;
    }
    set
    {
        _newPassword = value;
    }
}

public object Parent
{
    get
    {
        return _parent;
    }
    set
    {
        _parent = value;
    }
}

public ChangePasswordEventArgs()
{    }

public ChangePasswordEventArgs(string pass , object parent)
{
    _newPassword = pass;
    _parent = parent;
}
```

}

**Default.aspx**

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<%@ Register TagName="ChangePasword" TagPrefix="MY" Src="~/User Controls/ChangePassword.ascx" %>
<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
     <MY:ChangePasword ID="passControl" runat="server" />
</asp:Content>
```

**Default.aspx.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    passControl.ChangePasswordEvent += new User_Controls_ChangePassword.ChangePasswordDelegate(passControl_ChangePasswordEvent);
}

void passControl_ChangePasswordEvent(object sender, ChangePasswordEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Parent != null)
    {
        User_Controls_ChangePassword cp = (User_Controls_ChangePassword)e.Parent;
        cp.FindControl("successMessage").Visible = true;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: read [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/events.aspx)

Comment: Thanks. Its a nice article about delegates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you Meysam. He commented on my question with a very useful link regarding delegates. Now I have a clear idea about delegates and also about EventArgs. Here is the link,

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4773/Events-and-Delegates-Simplified

Hope it will help others too.

Answer (score 0):

You can see a good example of usage of delegates in lambda expressions. It is used frequently in LINQ.

Take a look here: [Lambda Expressions and Expression Trees](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb308959.aspx)

Also you can refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/191153/when-would-you-use-delegates-in-c) post.

The example you have provided is form the category *Event handlers (for GUI and more)*

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the use of delegates for event handling there is a generic solution for it since .NET 2.0

[`EventHandler<TEventArgs>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/db0etb8x%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Handling events using this doesn't require explicit use of new delegates.

This event declaration is enough:

```
event EventHandler<ChangePasswordEventArgs> ChangingPassword;
```

---

In your code when raising an event you should check for subscribers:

```
void changePass_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if(ChangePasswordEvent != null)
        ChangePasswordEvent(sender, 
            new ChangePasswordEventArgs(newPassText.Text, this));
}
```

If you don't check for subscribers and there are none, the event would throw an exception. In a multi threaded application you should use [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/282741/66849) instead.

---

Regarding the general use for delegates, the "raw" delegate is seldom used directly, but events, [lambdas](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx) and expression trees use delegates as the underlying mechanism. The only direct use for delegates I have made is for event handling and [async operations using the Begin/EndInvoke pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/22t547yb%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

See [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/47887/C-Delegates-Anonymous-Methods-and-Lambda-Expressio) for an explanation of delegates, lambdas and anonymous methods.